# Two-frame SVG animation: do the last frame need to be specified twice?

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I want to have a smooth one-time transition between two frames. The animation should stop at the last frame. This works as expected:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 400 400" width="50%" height="50%">
          <path d="M100 200 c-50,-100 150,-100 200,0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" fill="none">
            <animate
                     dur="2"
                     attributeName="d"
                     values="M100 200 c50,-100  250,-100 200,0; M100 200 c-50,-100 150,-100 200,0"
                     keySplines="0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5">
            </animate>
          </path>
</svg>
```

However, I need to specify the last frame path twice: the second time in the `d` tag. Otherwise, the image eventually disappears. Any pure-SVG method of having such a animation with each frame specified only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this perhaps. I've reversed the paths so the initial state is the base value and added fill="freeze" to retain the animation state once it's finished.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 400 400" width="100%" height="100%">
          <path d="M100 200 c50,-100  250,-100 200,0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" fill="none">
            <animate
                     dur="2"
                     attributeName="d"
                     to="M100 200 c-50,-100 150,-100 200,0" fill="freeze">
            </animate>
          </path>
</svg>
```